# Turn data table into a matrix

Tags: python-2.7, list, matrix, vector

I'm really desperate since I can't create a matrix using a given code. I am not allowed to use numpy or any other imported libraries.
Here's my code, which I will be translating since it's in Spanish so I'm really sorry if I miss a word or two:

```
start = float(input("First value of time: "))
incremento = float(input("Increase: "))
final = float(input("Final time: "))
max_height = 0.0
max_time = 0.0
print ("Tiempo\t Altitud(m)\t Velocidad(m/s)\t")
time = final
while (time <= final and time <= 48):
    height= -0.12*time**4+12*time**3-380*time**2+4100*time+220
    speed= -0.48*time**3+36*time**2-760*time+4100
    speed/= 3600

    print ("%.2f\t %.2f\t           %.2f\t" %(time, height, speed))
    if height> max_height:
        max_heigt= height
        max_time = time
    time+= incremento
print ("Maximum height is %.2f m in time %.2f." %(max_height, max_time ))
```

I'm supposed to create a matrix from the information printed as a table.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have a builtin matrix, so you'd want to store the information in a list of lists.
Before the `while` loop add `table = []`.
Inside the `while` loop, add `table.append([time, height, speed])`.